# Save Duplicate Data At SQLITE DB When Refresh the Browser

Tags: python-3.x, django, api, django-models, django-views

Basically, I am writing a Django application where I am calling third-party free API. After fetch the
data from API, I am trying to save the data into Django Model. I am created a model for storing API data.
After saving data in Django SQLITE DB, when I refresh the browser, exact same data again save in the SQLITE database table. How can i prevent this issue?

One logic in my mind:
if data is exist then no need to insert
otherwise insert

but i can't apply this logic in Django view because don't know how?

Models.py

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class DogFacts(models.Model):
    fact = models.CharField(max_length=100)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.fact
```

views.py

```
def api(request):

    url = 'https://dog-facts-api.herokuapp.com/api/v1/resources/dogs/all'
    response = requests.get(url)
    json_response = response.json()

    # save all dog facts in the db
    for i in json_response:
        dog_facts = DogFacts(fact= i.get("fact"))
        dog_facts.save()
    return redirect('api')
```

Thanks.

Answer (score 0):

I can think in two ways to do it.
1 - To change unique to True in the fact field (https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/3.2/ref/models/fields/#unique)
2 - Check everytime you call the api.
1 :

```
from django.db import models

# Create your models here.
class DogFacts(models.Model):
    fact = models.CharField(max_length=100, unique=True)

    def __str__(self):
        return self.fact

def api(request):

    url = 'https://dog-facts-api.herokuapp.com/api/v1/resources/dogs/all'
    response = requests.get(url)
    json_response = response.json()

    # save all dog facts in the db
    for i in json_response:
        try:
            dog_facts = DogFacts(fact= i.get("fact"))
            dog_facts.save()
        except Exception as e:
            print(e)
    return redirect('api')
```

or
2 :

```
    from django.db import models
    
    # Create your models here.
    class DogFacts(models.Model):
        fact = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    
        def __str__(self):
            return self.fact

    def api(request):
    
        url = 'https://dog-facts-api.herokuapp.com/api/v1/resources/dogs/all'
        response = requests.get(url)
        json_response = response.json()
    
        # save all dog facts in the db
        for i in json_response:
            dog_facts = DogFacts.objects.filter(fact= i.get("fact"))
            if len(dog_facts) == 0:
                dog_facts = DogFacts(fact= i.get("fact"))
                dog_facts.save()

        return redirect('api')
```